# Nova Compute Service throwing error nova requires Qemu version 2.1.0 or greater

Tags: centos7, openstack, devstack

Nova compute service is not running in the fresh devstack installation of OpenStack ;
giving an error

> nova requires Qemu version 2.1.0 or greater

when I checked version info I found the qemu-kvm version  2.9.0 was available but hypervisor was running on qemu 2.0.0
all other services are running fine.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qemu is provided by two different repos qemu-ev and EPEL.
libvert only sees qemu version  installed by epel repository. so removing epel repo and restarting libvirt service should fix the issue

```
sudo yum remove qemu-system-x86
sudo service libvirtd restart
sudo service devstack@n-cpu restart
```